# where filter returns empty array in Loopback3

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop

I have model named franchise form which I want to fetch data based on franchise name.
My query is

```
{"where":{"company_name":"test"}}
```

The strange thing is sometimes the filter works properly but sometimes it returns an empty Array. I am using `loopback3`.

Comment: `{"where":{"company_name":{"eq":"test"}}}` this may give you consistent results.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using MongoDB set this flag `"strictObjectIDCoercion": true` in the `options` object of your `[model].json` file.

Answer is explained here:
https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/3593#issuecomment-379353913